# Energy transfer by heat is dependent on the process path, does $Q=mc\Delta T$ says otherwise?

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a gas that goes from a state 1 ($P_1, V_1, T_1$) to state 2 ($P_2, V_2, T_2$) by a **process path A** during which energy was transferred by heat (say 20kJ). The heat transfer to the gas will be

$$Q=mc(T_2-T_1)=20kJ$$

Now, I've read that energy transfer by heat is dependent on the process path. So, I can even take another **process path B** to bring about the same change in state from 1 to 2, during which I add energy by heat. The energy transferred in process B by heat can be different while bringing the same change of state (say 40kJ).

Changing the process path changes the energy transferred by heat, but my  $Q=mc(T_2-T_1)=20kJ$ still remains the same, since T2 and T1 did not change.

[image]

Can anyone help me through this contradiction?

Comment: Is "m" the number of moles of the gas?

Comment: @Cross  No, m= mass of the gas and c average specific heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me through this contradiction?

There is no contradiction. The heat for the two paths must be different because the work done for the two paths is different. The mistake you are making is assuming a single value of specific heat $c$ for the heat transfer in the two processes.

The specific heat of a gas depends on the process. So the specific heat for path B is not the same as that for path A, i.e., there is no singe value of $c$ that applies to the two processes. (Specific heats are given for constant pressure and constant volume processes. Since neither path is a constant pressure or volume process, they do not apply).

The two paths cannot involve the same heat transfer because the two paths involve a different amount of work and heat and work are related by the first law.

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Since internal energy is a state function, $\Delta U$ is the same for both paths. Consequently

$$Q_{B}-W_{B}=Q_{A}-W_{A}$$

Since work is the area under the PV curve,

$$W_{A}\gt W_{B}$$

Therefore

$$Q_{A}\gt Q{B}$$

If the gas is an ideal gas, then for any process

$$\Delta U=mc_{v}\Delta T$$ So for processes A and B

$$Q_{A}=mc_{v}(T_{2}-T_{1})+\int_{A1}^{A2} pdV$$

$$Q_{B}=mc_{v}(T_{2}-T_{1})+\int_{B1}^{B2} pdV$$

> What if there was no work interaction involved? i.e. can I take a
> system from state 1 to 2, via distinct process paths if only heat
> transfer is allowed?

If no work were done then the process for a gas has to be a constant volume, and the heat would then be $Q=mc_{v}\Delta T$. But your example is not a constant volume process so it would not apply.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps, thank you. even though I feel I wasn't able to convey my doubt properly. What if there was no work interaction involved? i.e. can I take a system from state 1 to 2, via distinct process paths if only heat transfer is allowed? (i should add this sentence to my ques)

Comment: @HarshitRajput See update to my answer in response to your follow up question.

Comment: Oh. So, If there is no work interaction, all processes will be constant volume processes (right?) and between any two states 1 and 2, I can get several process paths for each constant volume (V1, V2, V3..) but in all these paths the heat transferred will be the same.

Comment: A constant volume wouldn't apply in your example since obviously the final and initial volumes are not the same. I revised my answer to that effect.

Comment: Now it has started to make sense. At a given constant volume, if I were to take the system from state 1 to 2, transferring energy only by heat then there will be a unique process path. There can't be any other process path to take the system from 1 to 2, transferring energy by only heat. Am I right?

Comment: @HarshitRajput For your equilibrium states that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your formula

$$Q=mc(T_2-T_1)$$

tells you how much energy that is needed to cause the wanted temperature change. This is the same regardless of how the energy is provided.

If you choose different paths, then you might experience different loss effects where energy is wasted along the way. If this is the case then we call the process non-conservative. Wasted energy will not be spend on the temperature rise, so the total amount of energy that must be provided is now larger, $E_\text{total}=Q+E_\text{wasted}$.

Note, that it is not uncommon to work with conservative processes in which case you can expect any heat loss along the way to be negligible. It is not given that you should assume the total heat energy provided to depend on the path.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Steeven, if energy was transferred to the system by heat only, and no energy loss took place from the system, during a state change, does that mean there is only one process path that can bring that change of state?

Comment: Steeven, "wasted" energy invariably turns into heat.  Whether or not that heat goes into the gas mentioned by the OP depends on the details of the process.

Comment: @DavidWhite I agree. Did I write something wrong?

Comment: @HarshitRajput Not necessarily. You could, at least theoretically, imagine reaching various states along the way without any energy loss.

Comment: Steeven, I'm not sure how to interpret the 2nd paragraph in your answer.  E-wasted may well be part of Q, depending on the process, and that energy may well contribute to the temperature rise.

Comment: @DavidWhite Alright, by "wasted" I mean all energy that does not in the end provide to the intended goal. Which in this case is a temperature rise

Answer (score 1):

For different processes that involve a change in temperature $\Delta T = T_f - T_i$ , the change in internal energy of the gas is the same, but the energy transfered by heat and work ($Q$ and $W$) need not have unique values.

A very common example is the molar specific heats for processes associated with constant pressure ($C_P$) and constant volume ($C_V$). They are not equal, and for an ideal gas, they are related as $C_P - C_V = R$. The relavant equations for the energy transferred by heat are then:
$$Q = nC_P\Delta T \ \text{(constant pressure)}$$
$$Q = nC_V\Delta T \ \text{(constant volume)}$$

We can explain the reason behind the difference qualitatively as follows:

At constant pressure, when energy is added to the gas, the internal energy of the gas increases, but (negative) work is done on the gas to maintain the constant pressure, and $Q = \Delta E_{int} - W_{ext}$ is greater than $\Delta E_{int}$. At constant volume however, no work is done (as the change in volume is zero), so $Q = \Delta E_{int}$. Clearly the energy transferred by heat at constant pressure is greater than the energy transferred by heat at constant volume and it follows that, $C_P ≠ C_V$.

Hence in summary, the energy transferred by heat is path dependent and the values of specific heats varies according to the path chosen. You can read more about it from the wikipedia article on [the variations in specific heats.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity#Variations)

Also note that the difference between $C_P$ and $C_V$ is negligible for solids and liquids as the change in volume is negligible for a relatively small range of temperatures.

Hope this helps.